# Intercepting push notification android c2dm from another application and using the notification in my app

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

Hi I have all the credentials on app 'A' push notification. I'm just wondering if app 'B' can also accept push notifications of app 'A'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, c2dm has been deprecated for a year now.  You shouldn't use it in new development,  and if you have apps already using it, you should migrate to Google Cloud Messaging.

In GCM,  when you using the same credentials for differnt apps, you still get different registration ids for the same device. Therefore one app cannot receive the notifications sent to another app. You must send the notification from the server to the registration ids of both apps.